# How do I solve "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing"?

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3. And I wanted to update by running `sudo apt update`. I got

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]      
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]    
Fetched 252 kB in 28s (8,883 B/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

After that I ran `apt list --upgradable`, I got

```
Listing... Done
libsnmp30/bionic-updates 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.1]
linux-generic-hwe-18.04/bionic-security,bionic-updates 5.0.0.36.94 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.0.23.80]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04/bionic-security,bionic-updates 5.0.0.36.94 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.0.23.80]
linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04/bionic-security,bionic-updates 5.0.0.36.94 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.0.23.80]
```

After this, I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libsnmp30
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 929 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsnmp30 amd64 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.173 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/libsnmp30_5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.173 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Here my repository:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports multiverse main restricted universe
```

How to fix with it?

Comment: There is something wrong with the repository. Try to set another source from software properties.

Comment: What do you mean? How to set another source?

Comment: By "Software & Updates"

Comment: [The website is down](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/uz.archive.ubuntu.com.html)

Comment: Any of above did not work for me

Comment: Are you using some proxy?

Comment: I am not using any proxy

Comment: Can you open [this](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/) on a browser?

Comment: Yes, I can. And I can download the package, but I can not install snmp.

Comment: Run`sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*; sudo apt update; sudo apt install -f`

Comment: This also did not work for me.